# Implementing radio select using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, multiple-select

I want to implement radio functionality between the groups using multiple select.

i.e. in Group A,

if user clicks A1 it has to deselect A2 and A3
if user clicks A2 it has to deselect A1 and A3
if user clicks A3 it has to deselect A1 and A2

i.e. in Group B,

if user clicks B1 it has to deselect B2 and B3
if user clicks B2 it has to deselect B1 and B3
if user clicks B3 it has to deselect B1 and B2

```html
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/multiple-select/1.2.0/multiple-select.min.js"></script>
      
          <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/multiple-select/1.2.0/multiple-select.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <select multiple="multiple">
            <optgroup label="Group A">
                <option value="1">Radio A1</option>
                <option value="2">Radio A2</option>
                <option value="3">Radio A3</option>            
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Group B">
                <option value="4">Radio B1</option>
                <option value="5">Radio B2</option>
                <option value="6">Radio B3</option>   
            </optgroup>
        </select>
        <script src="multiple-select.js"></script>
        <script>
            $('select').multipleSelect(
            {
                multiple: true,
                multipleWidth: 300,
            selectAll: false,
                width: '100%',
                
                onClick: function(view) {
                    //;
                }            
            }
            
            );
        </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: You can also just use the normal ```<input type="radio">```. It supports deselecting previous buttons when a new one is clicked as long as all of them have the same ```name```.

Comment: No this I tried but doesn't work

Comment: ```<form><input type="radio" name="test" value="test"><input type="radio" name="test" value="test"><input type="radio" name="test" value="test"></form>``` So this code does not display radio buttons that only allow one button to be selected at a time for you?

Answer (score 0):

On Click this checkbox,this checkbox's sibling checkbox's property`('checked')`will be changed to `false` ..

```
<body>
    <select multiple="multiple" id="multiselect">
        <optgroup label="Group A"  id="optgroup1">
            <option value="1" class='radioa'>Radio A1</option>
            <option value="2" class='radioa'>Radio A2</option>
            <option value="3"class='radioa'>Radio A3</option>            
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Group B"  id="optgroup2">
            <option value="4" class="radiob">Radio B1</option>
            <option value="5" class="radiob">Radio B2</option>
            <option value="6" class="radiob">Radio B3</option>   
        </optgroup>
    </select>
    <script src="multiple-select.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('select').multipleSelect(
        {
            multiple: true,
            multipleWidth: 300,
            selectAll: false,
            width: '100%'           
        });

        $(document).ready(function(){
         $(".radioa input[type='checkbox']").on('click', function() {
            if($(this).prop('checked')==false){
              $(this).prop('checked', false);
            }
           else{
               $('.radioa input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
               $(this).prop('checked', true);
            }
          });

         $(".radiob input[type='checkbox']").on('click', function() {        
            if($(this).prop('checked')==false){
              $(this).prop('checked', false);
            }
           else{
               $('.radiob input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
               $(this).prop('checked', true);
            }
          });                 
        });

    </script>
</body>
```

Ref about `siblings` here https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_siblings.asp

Comment: answering with code only and with no explanation is not a good answer

Comment: I tried but this doesn't work. I just put the alert in between your code, it gives no response, it is not invoked

Comment: Have u put my code inside this `$(document).ready(function(){  // code  });`?